# How to back up server with rsync, preserving ownership/permissions without root login

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am setting up a backup server on which I want to run rsync over ssh to backup content on other servers every night. I would like to set up ssh keys to make it password-less, but I want to preserve ownership of files and permissions. There are a number of users on the server to be backed up which won't all exist on the backup server.

What would be the best way to do this? I guess the backup job will need to connect as root to , but I don't want to enable root ssh access on the servers.

thanks for any tips,

oli

ps, all servers are running UBUNTU Server 12.04 LTS and are behind a university firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.  Linux REQUIRES you to have root access to save a file as any user other than yourself.  The ONLY workaround is to tarball it and then transfer the tarball to the server.

Comment: As a side note, you can enable root access over ssh on the server so long as you set `authorized_keys` to only allow a specific command (`rsync` in this case).  Use the `command` option in `authorized_keys` to set a specific key to only allow a specific command such as `/usr/bin/rsync`.  However, due to the security of ssh keys, if they have access to the root keys, you've got bigger issues on hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you just don't have root ssh access, but have sudo(8) rights on the machine, you can do it.

For example, by putting `username ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync` in `/etc/sudoers` on remote host and doing:

```
rsync -a -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" localdir/ username@remote.example.com:/remotedir
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/605425/rsync-root-files-between-systems-without-specifying-password/889313#889313) for details and more options of doing it.

Also, since users don't already exist on remote, you'll need to use `--numeric-ids` on your `rsync` line so they'll get preserved (but you'll only see their usernames and groups once you sync `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, of course)